# XSL: how to display an value based another attribute value?

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

I'm working on a DITA customization plug-in to generate a PDF with XEP engine (and based on DITA Open toolkit).
I'd like to have some content in a PDF layer (OCG), does anyone know if it's possible and if so, how?
Thanks,
Annette

Comment: I don;t understand the relationship between the question title and the question.

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed that the title I had set for another question had been kept :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RenderX XEP's PDF output does not support creating layers.

Comment: Ok, I'll try something else. Thanks.